# Batch retrieve 'dataValidation' for all cells in a sheet with gspread or gspread-formatting?

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, gspread

Using `Spreadsheet.fetch_sheet_metadata` returns *most* of the cell data I need, such as user-entered formatting. But I cannot figure out how to retrieve `dataValidation` data from cells. If I enter `"fields": "dataValidation"`, it fails and states that that is not a valid field.

```
resp = sheet.spreadsheet.fetch_sheet_metadata(
        {"includeGridData": True, "ranges": label, "fields": "*"}
    )
```

`gspread-formatting` provides a method to do this:

```
dv = gf.get_data_validation_rule(sheet, cell_label)
```

but this is not a batch request, so the API returns a "quota exceeded" message when I try to use this cell-by-cell on large sheets.

Is there a way to use either `gspread` or `gspread-formatting` to batch get the `dataValidation` entries for all cells?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't notice that you are using the service account and you can use googleapis for python. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. From your replying, I could confirm that my answer was not useful for your question. So I would like to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. But I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with a service account using discovery. Thanks Tanaike for the fields query!

```py
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from googleapiclient import discovery


credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_info(credentials)
credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
    scopes=[
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    ]
)
service = discovery.build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)
request = service.spreadsheets().get(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
    ranges=sheet_name,
    fields="sheets(data(rowData(values(dataValidation))))",
)
resp = request.execute()
```